# Why does the input value show in the console, but not in the dropdown boxes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, input, dropdown

I have built a basic reports program that accepts input from a user, adds this input to a series of paragraphs that are added to a dropdown list. The selection is then added to an array and printed in a final report.

[Here is a JFiddle of the program](https://jsfiddle.net/DanCUK89/rp2gfy8j/2/). As you'll see, your input is printed in the console, but it does not get pulled through to the dropdown. Can you help me figure out why?

```
function populateSelects(dropDownConfig) {
    console.log(`I can get the student name here, but not in the dropdown box. Your name is ${studentName}.`);

for (let di = 0; di < dropDownConfig.length; di++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dropDownConfig[di].categoryOptions.length; i++) {
    let opt = dropDownConfig[di].categoryOptions[i];

    let el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt;

    document.getElementById(dropDownConfig[di].id).add(el);
  }
}
}
```

The function seems to work okay, but not with the studentName/the value of the inputStudentName.

Thanks!

Comment: You never update `progressOptions`, `behaviourOptions` etc with the new inputted name. That's why it does not show properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your code a little bit to make it shorter and more readable, imho. The main change I made is to use placeholder text instead of variable and replace it with studentName while options are been creating.

```
let options= {
  progress: ['%NAME% has made excellent progress', '%NAME% has made good progress', '%NAME% has made poor progress'],
  behaviour: ['%NAME% has excellent behaviour', '%NAME% has good behaviour', '%NAME% has poor behaviour'],
  attendance: ['%NAME% has excellent attendance', '%NAME% has good attendance', '%NAME% has poor attendance'],
  punctuality: ['%NAME% has excellent punctuality', '%NAME% has good punctuality', '%NAME% has poor punctuality'],
  improvements: ['%NAME% should carry on as they have', '%NAME% could make some improvements', '%NAME% must improve']
}

let dropDownConfig = ["progress", "behaviour", "attendance", "punctuality", "improvements"];

function populateSelects(dropDownConfig) {
  dropDownConfig.forEach(config => {
    let select = document.querySelector(`#${config}Dropdown`);
    options[config].forEach(text => {
        let option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        text = text.replace("%NAME%", studentName);
        option.text = text;
        option.value = text;
        select.appendChild(option);
    })
  })
}
```